# Maximum Clique finder in Haskell - parse error

Tags: haskell, graph

I am trying to implement the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm for finding the number of maximum cliques (maximum Clique is a subset of a graph where every two verticies are connected and there is no larger clique containing it)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm

Unfortunately, I get an error : "parse error on input 'res' "
And I can't seem to solve it. I have tried to change the tap spaces with normal ones, but it doesn't seem to work. I also don't see any errors? Any ideas?

```
    type Clique = [Vertex]
swarming::Clique->[Vertex]->[Vertex]->[Clique]
swarming R P X =
    if null P && null X then [R]
                        else loop R X
                    where
                        loop::[Vertex]->[Vertex]->[Clique]
                        loop[] _    =[]
                        loop(v:R') X=
                            swarming (v:R)(P 'res' v)(X 'res' v)
                            loop P (v:X)

type Vertex = Int
class Graph g where
    size            ::g->Int
    verticies       ::g->[Vertex]
    connected       ::g->Vertex->Vertex->Bool

bron::Graph g=>g->[Clique]
bron g = swarming[] (verticies g) []
    where
        swarming R P X =
                if null P && null X then [R]
                        else loop R X
                    where
                        loop::[Vertex]->[Vertex]->[Clique]
                        loop[] _    =[]
                        loop(v:R) X=
                            swarming (v:R)(P 'res' v)(X 'res' v)
                            loop P (v:X)
                       res::[Vertex]->Vertex->[Vertex]
                       res  vs v = filter(connected g v) vs
```

Comment: I believe you need to use backticks instead of single quotes for infix notation. `P 'res' v` doesn't seem valid Haskell to me.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see there is a bit more wrong with your code than just the error you get:

- first of all as the comment already says `'` are reserved for single characters `Char`, the syntax you are looking for is `` `res` ``.
- secondly I saw you are using tabs, newer versions of the ghc compiler will warn you about that, usually nowadays people use spaces (this is mostly a matter of taste and it is up to you)

I have slightly reordered your code and modified it in such a way it compiles. The `undefined` will raise a run-time error, but this state is better than a non-compiling one.

```
type Clique = [Vertex]
type Vertex = Int

class Graph g where
  size      :: g -> Int
  vertices  :: g -> [Vertex]
  connected :: g -> Vertex -> Vertex -> Bool
```

I usually organize my code in a way that `type`/`data`/`class` declarations are on top of my file and the rest below that.

Syntax wise the next error you have is using upper case letters for variable names - this is not allowed in haskell. Types start with upper case variables with lower case.

`bron` is a tricky function and I honestly cannot quite figure out what you want to do there are two things that make this hard to figure out.

1. You have 'variables' `r` and `r` in both swarming and loop - it seems that they should be not the same, whereas `p` should be always the same.
   Name shadowing is not a syntactic problem but a logical, it makes it easier if two different things have not the same name.
2. I see

   ```
   loop ... = swarming
              loop
   ```

   this is invalid haskell syntax - what are you going to do with swarming it is not used in the following parts of the code, use `let … in` to stitch those two lines together

here is the rest of your code `bron` with a compiling but incomplete implementation

```
bron :: Graph g => g -> [Clique]
bron g = swarming [] (vertices g) []
  where res :: [Vertex] -> Vertex -> [Vertex]
        res vs v = filter (connected g v) vs

        swarming :: Clique -> [Vertex] -> [Vertex] -> [Clique]
        swarming r [] [] = [r]
        swarming r p x   = loop r x
          where loop :: [Vertex] -> [Vertex] -> [Clique]
                loop [] _    = []
                loop (v:r) x = undefined
                            -- let sw = swarming (v:x) (p `res` v) (x `res` v)
                            -- in loop ??
```